# Docker Desktop на виртуальной машине Win 10 на VMware vCenter Server

Tags: windows, docker, vmware

Можно ли установить Docker Desktop на виртуальную машину Win10, которая крутится в VMware vCenter Server? Hyper-v включена на виртуалке, но Docker все равно не запускается. Может надо в самом vCenter что-то делать? Или вариант с Docker Toolbox поможет? Конечно, извращения, но всё же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не выйдет. Hyper-v требует аппаратной поддержки виртуализации и монопольного доступа к функциям виртуализации. Внутри другой виртуальной машины вы этого добиться не сможете

Comment: Спасибо, проблема вот в чём. Я разрабатываю кросс-платформенное приложение. На Linux одним их вариантов распространения приложения являются docker-образы. Я знаю, что линуксовые docker-контейнеры работают под windows, но с оверхедом. Какая альтернатива этому на винде: собирать windows образы на физической машине или что-то другое?